# Transaction support in struts2

Tags: spring, transactions, struts2, guice, service-layer

I am using struts2.0 for my project named **online examination system**.

I am using traditional JDBC approach in datya access layer. I can't use JPA.

I want to make entire service layer transactional, but i searched for the transaction support in struts2 but didn't get anything.

Although spring provides good support for making service layer transactional.

Please help me on this issue to find out transaction support in struts2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on a wrong track here.Struts2 is only for MVC part and what you are doing at your service layer it has nothing to do with that.

If you want to take advantage of transaction API i suggest you to use either Spring AOP of if i am correct Google Guice also provides a way for AOP.

Whatever you use at your service layer for transaction handling Struts2 is independent of it and out of context

Comment: You are going to need to have an understanding of transactions in your underlying DB, then you can use AOP to cover most bases.  Just out of curiosity why is JPA out?  I find it quite easy to use in even small projects and its transactional support is excellent.